# Randomly choosing two elements in a list

Tags: python, random

Is there a better way to select two distinct elements from a list?

```
foo = ['1','a','3','f','ed']

elt1 = random.choice(foo)
elt2 = random.choice(foo)

while elt2 == elt1:
    elt2 = random.choice(foo)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
elt1, elt2 = random.sample(foo, 2)
```

`random.sample()` will pick `k` unique elements from the given population, at random:

> Return a *k* length list of unique elements chosen from the *population* sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Comment: Unique w.r.t. position, not value. `random.sample([1,2,1] 2)` can be `[1,1]`.

Comment: @delnan: Indeed, replaced 'values' with 'elements'; that was the wrong term to use.